# Mulesoft CXF Processing

Tags: java, web-services, soap, mule

I cannot seem to figure out how to continue to process the payload for a given SOAP Web Service.

I am sending an Outbound Message from Salesforce and attempting to consume it within Mulesoft. I can receive the message, and process it through CXF as JAX-WS Service.

[image]

I would like to do this CXF >> JAVA >> GET RELEVENT VALUE FROM PAYLOAD >> DO MORE STUFF.

This is the issue I am having, I can reference the values from within the Java class, but after that I am lost. Also the Java class implements a interface which returns a boolean based on the WSDL.

What can I do? Should I use a Proxy Service and just work off the XML String?

Answer (score 0):

Choose only body in CXF component and transform the XML to Java using transformer as a java collection and use the java class.

Comment: Why though? What makes that method better? I am ideally looking to return an acknowledgement response once I receive the request to prevent SFDC from continuously retrying to send the outbound messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Payload annotation in Java component to access the payload, but prior transformation is required.  please check

https://dzone.com/articles/mulesoft-payload-annotation-usage-in-java-componen